# What's spin liquid and how it connects quantum error correction?

Tags: condensed-matter, spin-models, quantum-error-correction

I understand how a bit flip code in a 2D lattice is like a 2D Ising model in Kitaev's 2001 paper [Topological Quantum Memory](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0110143). But generally, can someone explain how quantum error correction connects to those statistical/thermal physics models and what are phase transitions? I understand quantum error correction like surface code and come from a computer science background.

Comment: Wikipedia has a qualitative video about spin liquids: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Frustrated_magnetism.webm

Comment: It's very nice and intuitive, thank you!